# Rspec - How can I stub a constant that is defined in config/environment.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have defined a constant in `config/environment.rb` called LOCAL_SETTINGS that I use for configuration and use throughout my app. It's a YAML file stored in `config/local_settings.yml` and will sometimes contain sensitive data like API keys etc.

I'm currently trying to write a spec for a method that uses `LOCAL_SETTINGS["slack"]["slack_token"]`.

The problem is that the constant is not being stubbed for my expectations.  ie `expect(subject.path).to eq(help_request)` fails because it returns a path including the non-stubbed `LOCAL_SETTINGS` hash.

However if I put a debugger in beneath `stub_const` and then type `LOCAL_SETTINGS`, I can see that stub_const has worked.

My questions are:

1. Is there something I can do in Rspec to get stubs working for constants defined in `config/environment.rb`?
2. Should I simply define this constant elsewhere? If so, where? I will need access to it throughout my application in the app/ lib/ and spec/ folders.

My `config/environment.rb` file:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative 'application'

LOCAL_SETTINGS = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/local_settings.yml")

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

My spec:

```
describe RequestBuilder, type: :model do
  let(:help_params) { {"user_name"=>"some_user_name", "text"=>"release-bot help"} }
  let(:help_builder) { RequestBuilder.new(help_params) }
  let(:help_request) { "/api/files.upload?file=lib%2Fresponses%2Fhelp&filetype=ruby&channels=stubbed_channel&token=stubbed_token" }
  let(:slack_settings) { {"slack"=>{"slack_token"=>"stubbed_token", "slack_channel"=>"stubbed_channel"}} }

  context 'Given an incoming request' do
    context 'With a correctly formatted request' do
      context 'And the "help" command' do

        subject { help_builder.build_request_hash }

        it 'builds a request containing the help data' do
          stub_const("LOCAL_SETTINGS", slack_settings)

          expect(subject).to have_key(:request)
          expect(subject[:request].path).to eq(help_request)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Rails, and you already have a `.yaml` file in the config directory, I would suggest looking at [Rails custom configuration](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#custom-configuration) to load the YAML file. This way you'll be able to isolate any credentials from your test environment without having to stub the `LOCAL_SETTINGS` const for every test or change any of your classes.

```
# config/local_settings.yml
development:
    slack_token: some_dev_token
    slack_channel: some_channel

test:
    slack_token: fake_token
    slack_channel: fake_channel

production:
    slack_token: <%= ENV['SLACK_TOKEN'] %>
    slack_channel: <%= ENV['SLACK_CHANNEL'] %>
```

And then to load this configuration file:

```
# config/application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.local_settings = config_for(:local_settings)
  end
end
```

Then you can access the values from `Rails.configuration.local_settings['slack_token']` rather than from the `LOCAL_SETTINGS` constant.

Another [blog post highlighting the custom configuration](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/the-lesser-known-features-in-rails-4-dot-2/).